# Definition arithmetic progressions of any given length.

Tags: arithmetic

I have been studying erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions for some time and have an interesting question for you :

How do I strictly define "a set containing arithmetic progressions of any given length"

And can somebody give me an example of such a set?

Thank you in advance, you guys are awesome

Comment: set containing all possible arithmetic progressions of any length or just set which contains some arithmetic progression for any given length?

Comment: For any given $k \in \mathbb N$, the set contains an arithmetic progression of length $k$.  An example of such a set is $\mathbb N$ itself, which contains the arithmetic progression $1,2,\ldots,k$.  There are more interesting examples, such as the set of all primes.  I don't see what you have been studying about the Erdős conjecture without actually understanding the statement of the conjecture itself?

Comment: Hi Erick and Mihail, thank you for the quick response! Erick one more question, is it "an arithmetic progression" or "infinite many arithmetic progressions"?

Comment: @Thomas It makes no difference.  If a set contains an arithmetic progression of each finite length, then it contains infinitely many arithmetic progressions of each finite length.  Just think about how an arithmetic progression of length $100$ contains several arithmetic progressions of length $10$.  What have you studied about this conjecture so far?